# get content - Powershell

Tags: powershell

i wanna change mtu with powershell script and the value in this txt file

- when i get content it gives me this error
- Invalid mtu parameter (1492 ).
  [image]

- what's wrong in this code ?

```
$GMTU = Get-Content C:\MTU2.txt
$AdapterName = $(Get-NetAdapter | Where { $_.Name -Match 'Ethernet'}).Name
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "$AdapterName" mtu=$GMTU store=persistent
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there's a trailing space after the last digit. You can use `string.Trim()` to remove leading or trailing whitespace:

```
$GMTU = (Get-Content C:\MTU2.txt -TotalCount 1).Trim()
```